# I am embedding a Swing JPanel insidea SwingView component, and I am getting a specific error

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2

I am embedding a Swing JPanel inside a SwingView JavaFx2.0 component, and I am getting an error.

SEVERE: javafx.scene.control.Control impl_processCSS The -fx-skin property has not been defined in CSS for SwingView@52c03865

If you know what this means or how to fix it I would appreciate the help. The result of this happening is that the Swing compponent is not showing up within the Java Fx 2.0 Stage.

Comment: Have you tried to define the -fx-skin property in CSS?

Comment: just a sidenote: embedding swing into JavaFX2 apps is not recommended. Why do you need that?

Comment: I actually just need to be able to draw characters on a white background. I saw that you referred someone else to a third party library on another post so I went ahead and tried it out. Also I do not know how to set the -fx-skin property in CSS

Comment: Draw characters on white background? Did you try to use `javafx.scene.text.Text`?

Comment: Each character needs to be draw with a specific width, and the width needs to be dynamic, relating to the position of the stage on the screen.

Comment: that's achievable using JavaFX

Comment: could you give me an idea of how that would be done?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8040/discussion-between-sergey-grinev-and-artur-g-vieira)